# Accessing CurrentUser on NancyContext outside Modules

Tags: ninject, nancy

I've currently implemented a RESTful service using NancyFx that uses TokenAuthentication to keep track of logged in users. For various activities I actually need to know which user has sent the request, so I added an `IUserContext` interface to the solution and in the Nancy project I implement the interface in an class that takes a `NancyContext` and returns username/claims/authentication status. Said `IUserContext` is passed into services through constructor injection using Ninject.

In the NinjectModule on application level I bind the interface like so:

`Bind<IUserContext>().To<UserContext>();`

This is required it seems as the `IUserContext` won't be bound to anything when Nancy instantiates all the modules for route discovery on first run and connecting to the server will result in a Ninject error.

In the bootstrapper I've overridden both the `RequestStartup` and `ConfigureRequestContainer` methods in order to rebind the IUserContext to a constant, like so:

```
    protected override void RequestStartup(IKernel container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

        TokenAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, new TokenAuthenticationConfiguration(container.Get<ITokenizer>()));
    }

    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(IKernel container, NancyContext context)
    {
        container.Rebind<IUserContext>()
            .ToConstant(new UserContext(context))
            .InSingletonScope();

        base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
    }
```

Both methods run happily, being the `ConfigureRequestContainer` executed before `RequestStartup`. However, no matter what I try here, the `IUserContext` being passed into my services will always receive a `NancyContext` not relevant to the current request being executed, almost as if the rebindings in the `ConfigureRequestContainer` method are ignored.

It gets strangers though: whenever I modify my module to take on both an `IUserContext` and one of the services that requires the `IUserContext`, like so:

```
public OrdersModule(IUserContext userContext, OrdersService orderService)
```

The `userContext` will actually wrap `NancyContext` of the request, the `orderService` will receive a different context, containing an empty `NancyContext`(as in, no request data, no user, etc.).

What's going on here? Am I missing something vital in the flow of creation from the various kernels or does Nancy cache various objects?

**EDIT:** I think Ninject + ChildKernel is the culprit here: I created a `NullContext` which I bind in the application Kernel and then bind to the proper UserContext in the `RequestStartup`. Whenever a service is being looked up in the ChildKernel it cannot find it, it will pass on the lookup to the parent Kernel which won't refer to the ChildKernel for subsequent lookups (it seems). The result: It won't resolve the IUserContext that I just bound in the RequestStartup method and it will resort the NullContext I've previously defined on the application's container.

Comment: Currently solved the problem by providing a nearly empty kernel at the application level, it only contains a module to load the TokenAuthentication related classes and I bind the modules containing the remainder of the application's classes at the RequestStartup. Feels very unsatisfactory because it means rebinding pretty much every binding per request.